# How to show BBC in smf fourm show when new topic?

Tags: cms

BBC in smf fourm not show when new topic.

How to setting its? I tried for find setting thanks

Comment: What does BBC mean? What does smf mean?

Comment: SMF = simple machines forum software and BBC = Bulletin Board Code (I'm assuming)

Comment: Just thought of something else... is it your forum or someone elses?

Answer (score 2):

In the Admin pages for SMF, click the Posts & Topics, there's a tab there called "Bulletin board code settings". Is the BBC enabled in there and are all the tags selected ?